# Quick question about the FinancialBond function

Tags: finance

If I want the fair price of a bond with coupon interval twice per year with interest rate $i$ p.a., I use "CouponInterval"->1/2. However, **the InterestRate should be the effective, or nominal interest rate?**

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all in the Documentation Center:

> By convention, yield to maturity and coupon specifications are assumed
>   to be nominal with a compounding interval equal to the coupon payment
>   interval. By using the EffectiveInterest function or a functional
>   interest rate specification, any desired compounding can be achieved.

(...)

> FinancialBond takes a nominal yield and assumes a compounding equal to
>   the coupon frequency. However, it may be desirable to use a different
>   compounding frequency. EffectiveInterest can be used to find a rate
>   that gives the correct effective discounting after being compounded at
>   the coupon frequency:

```
Solve[EffectiveInterest[r, 1/2] == EffectiveInterest[.05, 0], r]

{{r -> -4.05063}, {r -> 0.0506302}}

FinancialBond[{"FaceValue" -> 1000, "Coupon" -> .05, "Maturity" -> 10,
   "CouponInterval" -> 1/2}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.0506302, 
  "Settlement" -> .2}]
```

(* ==> 995.103 *)

Hence my advice:

Do with `Mathematica` what your lecturer desires :)

Comment: Thanks. I was searching on http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialBond.html and couldn't find that detail

Answer (score 0):

Through experimenting, I was able to realize my error and thus realize that the InterestRate is, in fact, **nominal**.

Comment: Well, it wasn't exactly an error, but rather a nice little demonstration of the many possible ways how they get our money :)